# onRestoreInstance() is not getting called

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am using onRestoreInstance() for retrieving the data saved in onSaveInstance, but in my application it is not being called when coming back to the activity again.

While my activity is running, I press Home key. Then if I am again starting the activity, onRestorInstance() is not being called thats why I am unable to retrieve the values.

Can anyone explain that exactly when the onRestoreInstance() method is called?

Comment: when activity is destroyed an recreated like orientation change then you can save and retrieve the same in onRestoreInstance() Override the onPause() and onResume() in your activity. Log a statement and check yourself

Answer (score 0):

Press Home key would not cause a ReCreate, just onPause(), but OnRestoreInstanceState() is called after onCreate() you can check this [Recreating](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).